# Spring Boot - Is it possible to disable an end-point

Tags: spring-boot, openapi

Assuming I have a controller like:

```
public class MyController {

  public String endpoint1() {...}

  public String endpoint2() {...}
}
```

I want to disable `endpoint1` for whatever reason in Spring.  Simply, just disable it so that it cannot be accessed.  So, I am not looking for how and what response to return in that case or how to secure that endpoint.  Just looking to simply disable the endpoint, something like `@Disabled` annotation on it or so.

**SOLUTION UPDATE:**

Thanks all who contributed.  I decided to go with @AdolinK suggestion .  However, that solution will only disable access to the controller resulting into 404 Not Found.  However, if you use OpenApi, your controller and all of its models such as request/response body will still show in swagger.

So, in addition to Adolin's suggestion and also added @Hidden OpenApi annotation to my controllers like:

In **application.properties**, set:

```
cars.controller.enabled=false
```

Then in your controller, use it.  To hide controller from the OpenApi/Swagger as well, you can use `@Hiden` tag:

```
@Hidden 
@ConditionalOnExpression("${cars.controller.enabled}")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/cars")  
public class Carontroller {
   ...
}
```

After this, every end point handled by this controller will return 404 Not Found and OpenApi/Swagger will not show the controllers nor any of its related schema objects such as CarRequestModel, CarResponseModel etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use @ConditionalOnExpression annotation.

```
public class MyController {

  @ConditionalOnExpression("${my.controller.enabled:false}")
  public String endpoint1() {...}

  public String endpoint2() {...}
}
```

In application.properties, you indicates that controller is enabled by default

```
my.controller.enabled=true
```

ConditionalOnExpression sets false your property, and doesn't allow access to end-point

Comment: Thank you.  But that will not disable schema for models as well.  For example, in OpenApi, doing this will no longer show the controller which is great, however, all schema related for the controller (e.g. EmployeeRequestModel parameter) will still show in OpenApi.  I would like to disable all related to that controller.  I will accept the answer as I wasnt clear about that.  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Why not remove the mapping annotation over that method?

Comment: Thank you.  But that will not disable schema for models as well.  I would like to disable all related to that controller

Answer (score 1):

Try this simple approach: You can define a property `is.enable.enpoint1` to turn on/off your endpoint in a flexible way.

If you turn off the endpoint, then return a `404` or `error` page, which depends on your situation.

```java
@Value("${is.enable.enpoint1}")
private String isEnableEnpoint1;
 
public String endpoint1() {
    if (!"true".equals(isEnableEnpoint1)) {
        return "404";  
    }
    // code
}
```